# Do similar matrices have same characteristic equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Since similar matrices have same eigenvalues and characteristic polynomials, then they must have the same characteristic equation, right?

Answer (score 12):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are square matrices such that $A = P B P^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $P$. Then
\begin{align*}\text{charpoly}(A,t) & = \det(A - tI)\\
& = \det(PBP^{-1} - tI)\\
& = \det(PBP^{-1}-tPP^{-1})\\
& = \det(P(B-tI)P^{-1})\\
& = \det(P)\det(B - tI) \det(P^{-1})\\
& = \det(P)\det(B - tI) \frac{1}{\det(P)}\\
& = \det(B-tI)\\
& = \text{charpoly}(B,t).
\end{align*}

This shows that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. Note that this proof relies on several facts. In particular, the determinant is multiplicative.

Answer (score 9):

Note that $\det (\lambda I -A) = \det S \det (\lambda I -A) \det S^{-1} = \det (\lambda I - S A S^{-1})$.